# How does memory leak detectors differentiate malloc called from application to the thirdparty malloc calls?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I see that the memory leak detector like valgrind detects memory leaks only of the malloc called at the application rather than the thirdparty library i.e It tracks the direct new call rather than the allocations done in stl containers in c++.

Comment: It's quite difficult to make STL containers leak, how do you determine that valgrind doesn't track those?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen if one writes `new std::vector<…>` (which for sure should never be done), and never calls `delete` on it, and valgrind would only mention the leak for `new`, but not for the allocation happened inside of the `std::vector` then the question would be valid why this internal allocation is not reported because that's also memory that leaked. Or if `std::vector` is a member of a class that for which an instance was created with `new` and this instance was not deleted.

Comment: @t.niese I'm asking, because it's seems somewhat unlikely - STL containers are header only, so they should be indistinguishable from user's code (unless valgrind would explicitly check for internal implementations for some reason). I suspect reading valgrind outputs incorrectly or expecting leak where there be none.

Comment: It's possible that valgrind is ignoring those allocations that it's told to ignore in its suppression files. It's well documented https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress

Comment: valgrind does not handle third party libraries specially. There is no logic or way to recognise the main application and its libraries from "standard or third party" libraries.  Valgrind detects calls to allocation functions (malloc, calloc, new, ...) and tracks the memory allocations for all the detected calls.

Comment: I was trying to build my own leak detector code using LD_PRELOAD malloc hooks but while running that with c++ program I see that my preloaded hook for malloc also gets called for stl containers which internally call malloc/new. I want to avoid those scenarios. I only want to track the malloc allocations of the applications. So wanted to know how does other leak detector implementations does it like valgrind.